# Can't drop nor find a constraint on foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've declared me a table and put in a constraint on one of the columns. Being ignorant (or maybe unwilling) of altering the table, I did it in one move like so.

```
drop table Test
create table Test(
  Id bigint primary key identity(1000,1),
  TypeId bigint not null foreign key references TestTypes(Id),
  StringValue nvarchar(100) null)
```

Now, the stupid server won't allow me to remove the table...

I've tried clicking around the the GUI. No luck there. I tried **adding** and **dropping** a new constraint by *ALTER*. To no avail. I tried looking in the table with constraints. It's empty.

So, the question is twosome.

1. How do I get rid of the stupid constraint?
2. What is the actual name if the stupid constraint?

Comment: Which constraint do you want to drop? The primary key or the foreign key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The foreign key. The primary key won't be an issue, I believe, should I ever need to drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [system catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to find the name and use that to drop the constraint.

This code drops the foreign key constraint on the column`TypeId`in the table`Test`

```
declare @n varchar(max) = 'alter table Test drop '

select @n = @n + fk.name 
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.columns c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id 
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name = 'TypeId' and t.name = 'Test'

exec (@n)
```

Comment: +½ for the reply and +½ for Bender. Just learned that there are two new seasons. Yey!

Comment: What, are there new seasons coming? That would be awesome :)

Comment: Sorry to get your hopes up. I meant the last, already aired seasons. I didn't know about them until recently. It's me being behind due to some tragic events in personal life that kept me off the TV. You can verify at TV.com but I'm sure you've seen them all already. Sorry, mate.